# Can I export an openlayer map as an image in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, export, openlayers

Is there a way to export the openlayer map as an image for the user to download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the map  is a javascript based image. So you might need to hack away to find the answer.

I would try and use http://drupal.org/project/print

It creates pdf the next best thing. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that would work.  I think you'd need to actually take a screen shot.  I'm pretty sure the print module won't really be able to encapsulate the javascript images in the PDF.

Maybe something like the Website Screenshot module when it's stable - http://drupal.org/project/website_screenshot

Answer (score 0):

What version you use?
If you used OpenLayers 3, the following link can help you:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/export-map.html